# Accessing !ENTITY statement and reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I have some xml files with !ENTITY Definitions and &file_reference;

And I can process these successfully.

However I would like to preprocess the files and access the !ENTITY Definitions to extract file names and also the &file_references and which section of xml they are in

An example XML file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE gdml [
    <!ENTITY materials SYSTEM "materialsOptical.xml"> 
    <!ENTITY solids_Mainz_v2 SYSTEM "solids_Mainz_v2.xml"> 
    <!ENTITY matrices_Mainz_v2 SYSTEM "matrices_Mainz_v2.xml">
]> 

<gdml xmlns:gdml="http://cern.ch/2001/Schemas/GDML"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema/gdml.xsd">


<define>
<constant name="PI" value="1.*pi"/>
&matrices_Mainz_v2;
</define>
&materials; 
&solids_Mainz_v2;

<structure>
.... continued...
```

My coding attempt looks like

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        #print "Encountered a start tag:", tag
        # Entity may not be in latest tag so handle outselves
        global currentSection
        if tag in ["define","materials","solids","structure"] :
           print("Section : "+tag)
           currentSection = tag

    def handle_decl(self, decl):
        # This gets called when the entity is declared
        print ("Encountered an Entity declaration ", decl)
        words = decl.split()
        wlen  = len(words)
        print (words)
        if words[3] == "<!ENTITY" and wlen == 7:
           # const that refers to a file
           word = words[6].split('"')[1]
           print("Entity "+words[4]+" : "+word)
           filesDict[words[4]] = word


    def handle_entityref(self, name):
        # This gets called when the entity is referenced
        # starttag may not be a section
        print ("Entity reference : "+ name)
        #tag = self.get_starttag_text()
        print ("Current Section  : "+ currentSection)
        FilesEntity = True
        sectionDict[currentSection] = filesDict[name]


#    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
#        print "Encountered an end tag :", tag

#    def handle_data(self, data):
#        print "Encountered some data  :", data

    def unknown_decl(data):
        print ("Encountered unknown data  :", data)

def preprocessHTML(doc,filename):
    # Add files object so user can change to organise files
    # from GDMLObjects import GDMLFiles, ViewProvider
    print ("Preprocessing file for Entities File Definitions")
    global FilesEntity, filesDict, sectionDict
    FilesEntity = False
    sectionDict = {} # Empty Dict
    filesDict = {}
    fp = io.open(filename)
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(fp.read())
    # myfiles = doc.addObject("App::FeaturePython","Export_Files")
    # GDMLFiles(myfiles,FilesEntity,sectionDict)
    print("End of Preprocessing")
```

When I run it only picks up on the first Entity

```
Preprocessing file for Entities File Definitions
Encountered an Entity declaration  DOCTYPE gdml [
    <!ENTITY materials SYSTEM "materialsOptical.xml"
['DOCTYPE', 'gdml', '[', '<!ENTITY', 'materials', 'SYSTEM', '"materialsOptical.xml"']
Entity materials : materialsOptical.xml
Section : define
Section : structure
End of Preprocessing
```

Comment: Can you please provide a proper [mcve]? This import statement does not work: `from GDMLObjects import GDMLFiles, ViewProvider`. We also don't have access to the XML files that are referenced in the entity declarations. In addition, the question is tagged "lxml", but you are not using lxml in the code.

Comment: Just comment out any statements that do not work. Should still produce the problem.

Comment: I should not have to do that. The onus is on you to provide code that runs.